# What are the differences between empty set, zero set and null set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What are the differences between empty set, zero set and null set?

If i'm right empty set and null set is the same which is {}
but zero set is {0} ?

Comment: Null, nada and zilch.

Answer (score 9):

The null set, also known as empty set, is the set containing no elements, denoted by $\emptyset$ or {}

The zero set of of a real-valued function f : X → R is the subset of X on which f(x) = 0.

Comment: +1. I would also add that we also see "null" used as an adjective, meaning "having measure zero". And, of course, there are non-empty sets which are null in this sense (which is why I never use "null set" to refer to the empty set).

Comment: @NoahSchweber :  I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set is always a set of measure $0$

Comment: @user1952009 Sadly, that's not true - I've seen "the null set" used to refer to the empty set frequently.

Answer (score 0):

One could say that "zero set" is both defined and declared, but "null set" and "empty set" are only defined.